# How to make box plot group by axis 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have dataframe:

```
id  meters  availability1   availability2   availability3
0   0   70  80  90
1   50  75  75  80
2   100 100 90  100
3   150 87  85  80
4   200 60  90  100
```

I want to create a box plot that shows me what is availability for each specific meter.
For example for 0-meter availability is from 90 to 70.
So I want to create box plot for each row, not column. I can not found how to apply this not changing the structure of my dataframe.

The code that I use is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

file = 'D:\\test_box_plot.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ";", usecols = ['availability1','availability2','availability3'])


sns.boxplot(x="variable", y="value", data=pd.melt(df))

plt.show()
```

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a possible solution, but I am not quite sure if I've understood what you wanted:

```
 boxMeters = sns.boxplot(x=0,y=1,data=df.transpose(), palette="Set3")
```

The trick here is to work with a transposed matrix of your dataframe.
I suggest you to print the transposed dataframe to know how to reference every column.

With the data you posted, my transposed dataframe is:

```
                0   1    2    3    4
id              0   1    2    3    4
meters          0  50  100  150  200
availability1  70  75  100   87   60
availability2  80  75   90   85   90
availability3  90  80  100   80  100
```

"meters" is just below the column addressed as 0 and the availability1 is the column 1.
You tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help!